# How to update distinct column in SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, replace, sql-update, distinct

In my table I have a column `Segment_No` which has duplicates. Now I want to update those duplicates.

[image: Table]

For example: the value **249X5601** is present in two rows. I want to change the second value to **249X5601R**

Comment: Can there be more that two records? If so, how is that dealt with? How is the first record distinguished? (Donation_ID? Registration_No? Both? Another (unshown) column?)

Comment: yes, it contains more than one record.only Segment_No should be updated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The general form would be as follows:

```
;with AllRows as (
    select Donation_ID,Registration_No,Segment_No,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
               PARTITION BY Segment_No
               order by <Suitable_Column>
           ) as rn
    from UnnamedTable
)
update AllRows set Segment_no = <New_Value>
where rn > 1
```

Where `<Suitable_Column>` gives the column(s) the define which row is "first" and which is second. `<New_Value>` defines how the new `Segment_no` value should be computed, and `rn` gives the row numbers - so the where clause is ignoring the "first" row.

So if there are only ever a max of two rows sharing a single `Segment_no` value, and the "first" is the one with the lowest `Donation_ID` value, then it would be:

```
;with AllRows as (
    select Donation_ID,Registration_No,Segment_No,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
               PARTITION BY Segment_No
               order by Donation_ID
           ) as rn
    from UnnamedTable
)
update AllRows set Segment_no = Segment_no + 'R'
where rn > 1
```

Comment: If that contains more than two duplicates...,