# Update a field only if it is empty in SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-update, unique, is-empty

i have column which is not **mandatory** up to now, now it becomes a **mandatory field and an unique field**, now it contains **empty**. now i want update that field. i am in quite confusion to do that.see the below picture.update the **segment_NO** with out dupicates

[image]

the answer should be like this

[image]

Comment: Is this not the same as http://stackoverflow.com/q/19488352/50447?

Answer (score 0):

You can write the update query in a loop which test for null condition.

Comment: are you using interface for updation?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add some details to the question. 
Still you can use simple INSERT query to insert in the table or either you can use Update query to update a record. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8hwekas8%28v=vs.80%29.aspx
Refer this URL for further reference.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly specify the issue bluntly and with out any confusions.. Well somewhat i can understand is... You should update your DB table and make a primary key of two columns in composite style..

Hopefully this will be answer for your question